# Retrofit get current HTTP request method

Tags: java, twitter, retrofit

I am using RequestInterceptor to authorise a request to the twitter rest apis.
When creating the signature described here: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures
I need to get the current HTTP method GET or POST.
How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Anyone? Really stuck on this :(

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`Interceptor`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) from OkHttp instead of a `RequestInterceptor`  from retrofit.

```
class SigningInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override
  public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    final String method = request.method();

    // Build your sig and use it to build an auth header

    Request newRequest = request.newBuilder()
        .header("Authorization", /* the computed auth header */)
        .builder();

    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
  }
}
```

and add to your OkHttpClient --

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new SigningInterceptor());
```

and use `client` when building your retrofit instance.

Comment: What version of retrofit can I do that with?

Comment: What version are you using?  Should work in both 1.9.0 and 2.0.0 beta, but adding the OkHttpClient is different on `Retrofit` vs `RestAdapter`.  You might need to explicitly add okhttp to your project, too